# Start tracking branches/tags on a git-svn repo that was tracking only trunk

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I've started tracking an svn repository with git by cloning only its trunk directory. Now I want to track the other stuff, but I don't want to have to clone it again just to use `--stdlayout` since it takes a long time to download and I already have most of the code locally. How do I change the repository layout to match svn trunk/branches/tags scheme without having to clone again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old `.git/config`:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = svn://host/project/trunk
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

New `.git/config`:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = svn://host/project
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Now run `git svn reset -r1 -p; git svn fetch; git svn rebase`.

No, it's not much different from doing a `git svn clone` anew -- adding branches means that `git` can see more merges which means the content `git` is tracking has changed so `git-svn` must regenerate everything.

Comment: Let me add that `git svn reset` will fail unless the release specified is not part of the project. I'm mentioning this as in some older versions the command would issue unclear error messages.