# No longer track branches with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have cloned a svn branch using git-svn and am tracking all folders and branches. I would like to drop everything and only track web/trunk/* (for rebase, dcommit, etc.)

Is there any way to do this without reinitializing the repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582392/start-tracking-branches-tags-on-a-git-svn-repo-that-was-tracking-only-trunk could give some idea here

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll always pull in all the remote revisions.  However, you can still stop tracking the branches and tags I believe by editing the .git/config file and removing the lines under the "svn-remote" section for "branches" and "tags".